# details in hive skew join optimize when there are multi skew keys

Tags: join, hive, skew

**There are three questions aimed at some details on Hive skew join optimization：**

**Question 1**

In https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Skewed+Join+Optimization , we know the basic idea about hive skew join optimize... But  there are some details which trouble me:

for example:

select A.id from A join B on A.id = B.id

**in tableA ,there are three skew keys: id=1, id=2, id=3, the other keys are equally distributed, will it launch 4 MR jobs?**

job 1 to deal with the equally distributed keys ;

job 2 to deal with skew key id=1 ;

job 3 to deal with skew key id=2 ;

job 4 to deal with skew key id=3 ;

is  that  right ?  many  thanks .

**question 2**

as we  know ，the key point about skew join optimize  is that we can use **map join**  to **deal with the skew join key** ,such as 1 ,2 ,3 . So if  this does  not fit up with  the map join condition , will   it  fallback to ordinary join?

**question 3**

**the default setting is : hive.skewjoin.key= 100000**  , which is usually too small for practical query. Is it possible to decide dynamically the triggering conditions for skew join, for example based on the JVM heap size  and the total number rows  of the skew table?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

question 1 :
Not 4 jobs but 4 reducers each handling a  unique key